# bash can't find closing bracket?

Tags: bash, test, syntax

I am writing a bash script to makup the MariaDB instance on a Synology box. When I run it, it works, but I get an error:

```
admin@synology:/volume1/@appstore/MariaDB10/usr/local/bip$ ./mysql_backup
./mysql_backup: line 7: [: missing `]'

admin@synology:/volume1/@appstore/MariaDB10/usr/local/bip$ head -10 mysql_backup
#!/bin/bash

DBBACKUP=/volume1/remotebackup/mnt/devmysql.sql.gz
ERRFILE=/volume1/remotebackup/mnt/devmysqlerr.log


if [ -f "${DBBACKUP}.prev" && ! -f "${ERRFILE}" ] ; then
        rm -f "${DBBACKUP}.prev"
        mv "${DBBACKUP}" "${DBBACKUP}.prev"
fi
```

Adding a space and a second closing ']', I *still* get the same error. Nesting the 'if' statements provides a solution, but it's annoying me that something's not as I expect.

Comment: Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The syntax for two standard tests with an `&&` in-between them is

```bsh
[ expression_1 ] && [ expression_2 ]
```

or, using [the obsolete `-a` option](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128_16) (don't do this),

```bsh
[ expression_1 -a expression_2 ]
```

In your case, for example,

```bsh
if [   -f "$DBBACKUP.prev" ] &&
   [ ! -f "$ERRFILE"       ]
then
    mv "$DBBACKUP" "$DBBACKUP.prev"
fi
```

With `bash`, you may use `&&` as you have done, but only with the non-standard `[[ ... ]]` test:

```bsh
[[ expression_1 && expression_2 ]]
```

which could also be written as

```bsh
[[ expression_1 ]] && [[ expression_2 ]]
```

Except within the special `[[ ... ]]`, the `&&` is an shell operator that *separates two commands*, with the second being executed only if the first succeeds. So, given the command:

```bsh
[ expression_1 && expression_2 ]
```

The shell runs first `[ expression_1`, which is missing the trailing `]`, hence the error.

See also:

- [The POSIX specification for `test` and `[`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html).
- `man test` and/or `man [` gives you the manual for the *external* `test` and `[` commands.  Most shells have these commands built-in, but the semantics should be the same although some specific test operators may differ (there may be non-standard operators implemented).
- `help [`, `help test`, and `help [[` in a `bash` shell will show a short description of these built-in commands in the `bash` shell.  For further information about the `bash` shell built-ins, consult the `bash` manual (`man bash`).